# ggplot geom_tile correlation plot mix sorting axis tick labels creates strange plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I can't find any answers online, so hopefully someone has a solution.
I am trying to use ggplot2's `geom_tile` for plotting co-occurence/mutually exclusion graph with pairs of chromosome arms. Below is a snippet of my dataframe. (link to full dataset here: https://pastebin.com/imxfZNRX)

```
       Event1   Event2     label
1017 16p gain 16p loss exclusion
666  13q gain 13q loss exclusion
1523 19p gain 19q gain  co-occur
1565 19p gain  9q gain  co-occur
1738  1p loss  1q loss  co-occur
```

The name of chromosome arms are mix of number and letters. So I used `mixedsort()` from gtools to sort them. and factored my y/x-axis tick labels.

```
library(gtools)
library(dplyr)

event1 <- mixedsort(unique(cooccur.table$Event1 %>% as.vector()), decreasing = F); event1
event2 <- mixedsort(unique(cooccur.table$Event2 %>% as.vector()), decreasing = T); event2
cooccur.table$Event1 <- factor(cooccur.table$Event1, levels = event1)
cooccur.table$Event2 <- factor(cooccur.table$Event2, levels = event2)
```

and when I tried to plot,

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(cooccur.table, aes(x = Event1, y = Event2, fill = label, label = label)) + 
  geom_tile(colour="black") +
  coord_equal() + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#08d9d6", "#e84a5f", "#ffffff")) +
  # scale_y_discrete(limits = rev(levels(cooccur.table$Event1)[2:72])) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust = 1.4), 
        axis.text.y = element_text(hjust = 1.5),
        legend.position = "right",     
        axis.line.x = element_line(size = 0.2), 
        axis.line.y = element_line(size = 0.2),
        axis.ticks = element_blank())
```

this is the result...

[image: messed up correlation plot]

(I'm thinking since it's pairwise comparison, `geom_tile` is trying to get rid of that one so it staggers the comparison, but it's getting confused with the sorting... but I haven't no idea how to fix it so I get a triangle plot)

Comment: Can you include the results from `dput(cooccur.table)` into your question?

Comment: Hi Lin, I added a link to pastebin, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (explanations in comments):

```
# create ONE set of factor levels that cover both columns
event.levels <- mixedsort(unique(c(cooccur.table$Event1, cooccur.table$Event2)))

# create combined table such that we have both Event1-Event2 and Event2-Event1 pairs
new.cooccur.table <- rbind(cooccur.table,
                           cooccur.table %>% 
                             rename(Event2 = Event1, Event1 = Event2) %>% 
                             select(Event1, Event2, label)) %>%

  # convert both event columns to factor, with the same set of factor levels defined above
  mutate(across(starts_with("Event"),
                ~factor(.x, levels = event.levels))) %>%

  # keep only rows where Event1's is smaller than Event2 (this creates the triangle)
  filter(as.integer(Event1) < as.integer(Event2)) %>%

  # reverse the factor level order for Event2
  mutate(Event2 = forcats::fct_rev(Event2))

# plot
ggplot(new.cooccur.table, 
       aes(x = Event1, y = Event2, fill = label, label = label)) + 
  geom_tile(colour="black") +
  coord_equal() + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#08d9d6", "#e84a5f", "#ffffff"))
```

[image: result]

Small data sample for reproducibility:

```
cooccur.table <- structure(list(Event1 = c("9p gain", "19q gain", "19p gain", 
"9q gain", "10q gain", "19p gain", "19p gain", "9p gain", "19p gain", 
"19q gain", "10q gain", "10q gain", "9p loss", "19p loss", "10q loss", 
"19q loss", "19p loss", "19p gain", "10q loss", "10q loss", "10q loss", 
"19q gain", "9p loss", "19p loss", "19q loss", "19p gain", "10q gain", 
"10q gain", "19p loss", "19q gain", "10q gain", "19p loss", "10q loss", 
"10q loss", "19q loss", "19q loss", "10q gain", "19p gain", "10q gain", 
"19p loss", "10q gain", "19q gain", "10q loss", "10q loss", "9p gain"
), Event2 = c("9p loss", "19q loss", "19p loss", "9q loss", "10q loss", 
"19q gain", "9q gain", "9q gain", "19q loss", "9q gain", "19p gain", 
"9q gain", "9q loss", "19q loss", "9q loss", "9q loss", "9q loss", 
"9q loss", "9p loss", "19p loss", "19q loss", "9p gain", "9q gain", 
"9p loss", "9p loss", "9p loss", "9p gain", "19q gain", "9q gain", 
"9p loss", "19q loss", "9p gain", "19q gain", "9p gain", "9q gain", 
"9p gain", "9q loss", "9p gain", "9p loss", "19q gain", "19p loss", 
"9q loss", "9q gain", "19p gain", "9q loss"), label = c("exclusion", 
"exclusion", "exclusion", "exclusion", "exclusion", "co-occur", 
"co-occur", "co-occur", "exclusion", "co-occur", "co-occur", 
"co-occur", "co-occur", "co-occur", "neutral", "neutral", "neutral", 
"neutral", "neutral", "neutral", "neutral", "neutral", "neutral", 
"neutral", "neutral", "neutral", "neutral", "neutral", "neutral", 
"neutral", "neutral", "neutral", "neutral", "neutral", "neutral", 
"neutral", "neutral", "neutral", "neutral", "neutral", "neutral", 
"neutral", "neutral", "neutral", "neutral")), row.names = c(NA, 
-45L), class = "data.frame")
```

Illustration with sample data:

[image: illustration]